# In angular 4how to use tel: in a *ngHref

Tags: javascript, angular, routerlink

I am using angular 4 and in template (.html), I coded as

```
<a *ngHref="tel:{{orders.billing_address.telephone}}"> <span> Call : </span>
```

It throws an error as

> Can't bind to 'href' since it isn't a known native property a

I search it and get angular 4 use [routerLink]. But I don't know how to use [routerLink] to set tel: numbers. Could you please guide me.

Comment: Please visit https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `href` inside `[]`. It will let you to remove `{{}}` part. And if you want to concatenate strings inside, you need to create a string like `'tel:' + otherParts`

```
<a [href]="'tel:' + orders.billing_address.telephone"> <span> Call : </span>
```

Answer (score 4):

use the `[href]` in angular 2

```
<a [href]="'tel:'+ orders.billing_address.telephone"> <span> Call : </span>
```